# Amazon load balancer with cognito returning 401 after sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-cognito, amazon-elb

We have an Amazon Load Balancer sitting in front of our application with Cognito as our IdP. We can get to the login page. After the user logs in, they get a "401 Unauthorized" page with the url:

https://xxxxx.com/oauth2/idpresponse?code=xxxx&state=xxxx

What could be some reasons why we're getting this error? Amazon seems to have very light docs around this [0] & [1]. We've already made sure all the oauth2 endpoints are correct (oauth2/token, oauth2/authorize, etc). Not sure where else to look.

Our setup roughly looks like this: https://www.exampleloadbalancer.com/auth_detail.html

[0] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-401-issues

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-configure-authentication-alb/

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Turns out the user facing the 401's was using a proxy in their network. That proxy was blocking my website for whatever reason (aka in the end, this had nothing to do with cognito).